# How can I Construct key pair values using strings in CPP?

Tags: c++, poco

1. I used poco json for key pair values, and it consuming more time(Sending Images consuming more time).

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buff, buff1;

cv::imencode(".png", image1, buff);

cv::imencode(".png", image2, buff1);

Poco::JSON::Object obj;

obj.set("photo1", buff);

obj.set("photo2", buff1);

std::stringstream ss;

obj.stringify(ss);
```

2. I want to construct same in terms of string in CPP.

```
cv::imencode(".png", image1, buff);

cv::imencode(".png", image2, buff1);

std::string data ="{\"photo1\":" +std::string(buff.begin(),buff.end());

data .append(",");

data.append("\"photo2"\":" + std::string(buff1.begin(),buff1.end()));

data.append("}");
```

3. If I Done step 2 How can i extract back the imencode data.
4. I tried converting json string.

   a) imencode-> string -> stringstream.
5. I want to construct key pair value in terms of string.

## Minimal Code

```
std::string stringifyTheBothImages(cv::Mat image, cv::Mat image1) {  

    std::ostringstream ostr;
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer, buffer1;
    cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer);                                                                    
    std::string address_json = "{\"photo1\":"  + data;
    address_json.append(",");
    address_json.append("\"photo2\":" + data);
    address_json.append("}");                                                      
    return  address_json;                                      
}   

int main(){                                                                                
   cv::Mat image = 
   cv::imread("C:/Amar/dec_16_2022_slabs/train/class0/image0.png", 1); 

   data2 = stringifyTheBothImages(image, image);        
   Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
   auto result = parser.parse(data2);
   Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr ptr_object = 
   result.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
   std::cout << ptr_object->get("photo1").toString() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need a JSON reader to extract key value pairs, then use cv::imdecode.

Comment: I tried that it throwing error.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you tried and the error.

Comment: When i am using opencv matrix data converting to imencode ,that converting  to string it's working and when i Extract back it's showing invalid index /0x86 like this.

Comment: Are you able to open this image in your system? Also, please edit the question and include all necessary details there.

Comment: With poco json set method it's working.

Comment: Print out the JSON with both methods. My guess is that when adding a string value to a key, you are missing double quotes.

Comment: With json method -> {"photo1":[image data numbars],"photo2":[image data numbers]}      with string -> {"photo1": human not readable data(bytes) ,"photo2": bytes}

Answer (score 0):

Since with JSON method you get an array of numbers for both the keys, you can do similar in C++ by converting each value in the buffer to an integer.

Also, instead of using `string::append` use `stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer1 = {129, 0, 234, 231, 255, 234, 13, 134, 2};
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer2 = {109, 0, 204, 201, 205, 204, 10, 104, 4};
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "{\"photo1\":[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer1.size(); i++)
    {
        ss << static_cast<int>(buffer1[i]);
        if (i != buffer1.size() - 1)
            ss << ',';
    }
    ss << "],\"photo2\":[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer2.size(); i++)
    {
        ss << static_cast<int>(buffer2[i]);
        if (i != buffer2.size() - 1)
            ss << ',';
    }
    ss << "]}";
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```